# Better SQL query In SQL Server for best performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (with same structure). One with 80 million records and other with 60 million records.
I want to delete records in 80m table that match in 60m table.
I use a sql query as below:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_80M
FROM tbl_80M INNER JOIN
tbl_60M ON tbl_80M.MobileNumber = tbl_60M.MobileNumber
```

In two tables, we have index on mobilenumber fields.
I run above query and it takes a long time .
Is there a better way to reach result in shorter time?

Note: tbl_80M has all of records that is in tbl_60M . I want to find and delete all records that are common in tbl_80M and tbl_60M.

Comment: How many rows match between the two tables? That is, what value is returned by the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_80m INNER JOIN tbl_60m ON tbl_80M.MobileNumber = tbl_60M.MobileNumber`.

Comment: Tanks, 60 Milions , My Porpuse Is To Delete Common Records In tbl_80M

Comment: You should look into when to use uppercase letters.

Comment: You're deleting 60 million rows - it's going to be at least a little slow. How much faster does it need to be?

Comment: Does the time really matter? Looks more like a one-time operation to me. Or do you plan to execute this every minute?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/methods-of-speeding-up-a-huge-delete-from-table-with-no-clauses

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a query to insert those N million records into a new table and then drop the old tables.

Then at last you can rename new table to tbl_80M.

```
SELECT
  * INTO tbl_NM
FROM tbl_80m a,
     tbl_60m b
WHERE tbl_80M.MobileNumber = tbl_60M.MobileNumber
```

Comment: tbl_80M has all of records that is in tbl_60M . I want to find and delete all records that are common in tbl_80M.

Comment: @student, Try writing the query yourself and add it to question. It will be something like below. Disclaimer:-  I have not tested this.
SELECT
  * INTO tbl_NM
FROM tbl_80m a,
     
WHERE tbl_80M.MobileNumber NOT IN (select MobileNumber from tbl_60M)

Comment: @student, Accept the answer if it is helpful :)